# Is there a way to define a generic serialization scheme with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a spring-boot project that is using Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to (de)serialize POJOs into JSON to interact with a 3rd party REST API.

The 3rd party API has a particular naming scheme for the properties that is internally consistent but not friendly towards the standard Java naming conventions. My question is, is there a way to configure the `objectMapper` to automatically handle this. Right now I'm using the `JsonProperty` annotation to explicitly associate each field with it's json property name and I wonder if I could remove these.

For example, the 3rd party wants everything to have a `p_` prefix and be all lower case so the `Pet` class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Pet {
   private String id
   private String petName
   private String species
}
```

should serialize to:

```
{
    "p_id" : <SOME.VALUE>,
    "p_petname" : <SOME.VALUE>,
    "p_species" : <SOME.VALUE>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@JsonNaming` annotation allows you to set the naming strategy used for the annotated classe’s properties: [JsonNaming](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonNaming.html)

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!